# Asp.net Core Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I want to implement Authorization in my Asp.Net Core project.
Here are the scenario.
1.Teacher Editor has permission to add student and course
2.Teacher Admin has permission to view student and course, but no edit permission
3.Student has permission to view course only.
Current, I check every request in different methods whether they have the permission. I am wondering whether there is any better way to control it in a center way.
I assume I could define a table which is used to identity who has which permission.
Any help would be appreciated.
Update:
Teacher has different level like level 1, leave 2. Different levels have different permissions. For the same method, I need to check user level and user admin or Editor.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles

Comment: Thanks, I am new to identity. How could I specify permission by multiple decide elements like teacher level and teacher admin? In addition, could I customize the unauthorized error message?

Comment: __How could I specify permission by multiple decide elements like teacher level and teacher admin?__ Click next topic on the documentation Mike linked for you... "Claims-Based Authorization", just below "Role based Authorization" . You can't expect us to do every little step for you?